# Data Science: Using Inferential Statistics to label train dataset

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, statistics, data-science

Lack of High Schools in remote areas is a problem for students in developing country. Students in some locations are better than that in other. So, I have to find those locations. Now, the main problem is defining "BETTER". I have made some rules that will define the profile of a location.

Right now, I am concerned with the good students.
So, what I have done is-
1.  Used some inferential statistics to and made some rules to come up with the conclusion that Location A,B,C,etc are the most potential locations where you can put the high schools because according to my rules these locations contain quality students.

I did all of the things above to label the data because I required to define "BETTER" and label the data so that I can now use machine learning algorithm to learn the factors which makes a location a potential location so that if I give a data point from test data to the model, it will instantly tell if the location is better or not.

Overview of the method:
For each location, I have these 4 information:
*total_students_staying_for_high_school_education(A)*,
*total_students_leaving_for_high_school_education_in_another_place*(B),
*mean_grade_point_of_students_of_type_B*,
*ratio (calculated as B/A)*,

For the location whose ratio > 1

- I applied the chi-squared significance test to come up with a statistic which would tell me if students are leaving that place in significant amount than staying. I used ANOVA and then Tukey test to compare means_grade points and then find combinations of pairs of locations whose means vary and whose is greater than the others.
- I then wrote a python program with a custom comparator that first compares if mean_grade of those points vary and returns the one with greater mean. If the means don't vary, the comparator return the location with the one whose chi-squared value is greater.

This is how, the whole process comes up with few suggestions of location and I call those location "BETTER".

What I am concerned about is-
 1. How do I verify if my rules are valid? Or do I even need to verify it?
 2. Most importantly, is mingling statistics with machine learning as described above an appropriate approach?Is there any major leakage in the method?Can anyone suggest a more general method?

Comment: "Mingling statistics with machine learning" is effectively machine learning, and this question is extraordinarily too broad. If you drill down into your _actual methodology_ with a specific question about model validation, it may be on topic on [Cross-Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks,.
The method is based on the intuition that "a location is said to have good quality students if they are scoring good grades collectively at other locations in their high school examination and of course students are leaving that particular location in significant amount". I have used statistical significant tests to come up with conlcusion. The calculations are statistical, I have not made any formula. By "my own rule"-i meant that I have decided to follow my intuition and common sense to take grade points and number of students- as a parameter for the statistical methods.

Comment: That isn't a _method_ though, that is a description of your problem. By actual methodology I mean what does your input data look like, what algorithm are you running it through and what is your output looking like.

Comment: I edited the question with the overview of the method as simply yet detailed as possible. Thanks

Comment: In addition to the suggestion from Mitch, [Data Science SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com) may also be a better fit once the question is narrowed down.